# Show that a binary relation ($a \le b$) or ($a = b$ and $c \leq d $) is an order relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, order-theory

I have to show that if there are $a + bi$, $c + di$ where $a,b,c,d\in C$ and $i=\sqrt(-1)$ and also

$a + bi \preceq c + di \iff $ $(a <b)$ or ($a=b$ and $c \leq d$)

the $ \preceq$ is an order relation in $C$.

How can we show antisymmetry, transitivity and reflexivity?

For the reflexivity, I think that we could say that b cannot be less than a, so, the $a \le b$. Since $a=b$ and $a \le b \iff a + bi \preceq a + bi $
What about the other two (antisymmetry and transitivity) ?

Comment: The definition of the alleged order relation is mis-stated. The roles of $b$ and $c$ should be interchanged on one side (butnot both sides) of the $\iff$.

Comment: I agree with you and probably the exercise is incorrect. However, one can say that I want to examine if this $\preceq$ is an order relation with this definition.I am also curious why the $a,b,c,d\in C$ and not $\in R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the relation is not even reflexive ?

Reflexivity requires that $z \preceq z \space \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$. But if $a>b$ then the conditions on the right hand side of the relation are not met so $a+bi \not \preceq c+di$. Hence, for example, $2+i \not \preceq 2+i$.

Comment: Is it possible?  Based on the relation $a \le b $ or $a = b$.

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis If $\le$ is intended to be an order relation on all of $\mathbb{C}$ then you need to show that  $z\le z$ for *any* $z\in \mathbb{C}$. One counterexample sinks the proof.

Comment: we have to show that $ z \preceq z $ not $ z \leq z $.

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis Point is that you cannot assume that $a \le b$ because reflexivity must apply to any $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I am very confused now. How is it possible to be $a > b $ ? If $a > b$ then we cannot have the $a + bi$ in the left side of the relation $a + bi \preceq c + di $. I mean that if we want to use this relation $a + bi \preceq c + di $ then this is $ a \leq  b$

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis If $a>b$ then the conditions on the right hand side are not met, so $a+bi \not \preceq c+di$.

Comment: That was very tricky. Please edit your answer to vote up